# How to avoid duplication while saving contact in android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I want to add my contacts from listview to contact page in android.. I am able to add contacts. But how do I avoid duplicates?

For example:
I have an entry with name Jony and number 123. If I press that same contact again it shouldn't be added to contact page. I dont want to add the contact if it is already in the contact page. How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
import_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newArrayList=null;

            //ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> selectedContact=null;
            ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

            newArrayList=ContactImportAdapter.contactsArrayList;

            for(int i=0;i<newArrayList.size();i++)
            {

                String name;
                String number;
                String mail;

            name=newArrayList.get(i).get("import_viewContactName");
            number=newArrayList.get(i).get("import_viewContactNumber");
            mail=newArrayList.get(i).get("import_viewContactMail");

            int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();

                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                        .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null).build());

                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                        .newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,rawContactInsertIndex)
                        .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name) // Name of the person
                        .build());                  


            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                        .newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(
                                ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,   rawContactInsertIndex)
                                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                                .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, number) // Number of the person
                                .withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_MOBILE).build());


                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, mail)
                       .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
                        .build());


    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contact Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
            }

            newArrayList.clear();
                try
                {
                    ContentProviderResult[] res = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                }
                catch (RemoteException e)
                { 
                    // error
                }
                catch (OperationApplicationException e) 
                {
                    // error
                }   



        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly To avoid duplicacy you will have to first call the database and check for the number if number exists then you can handle that.

Comment: Without database how to avoid duplicates.. I am using webservice to export my contacts

Comment: You have to maintain the records or contacts some where in the application and when every time you fetech or add a new contact it will compare your record of contacts.
For exampler you have contacts as 1234, 3423,5674,2345 now they are saved some where either in the arraylist or in some database it depends on you. Now when u add for example 1234 then this number will be ittrate thourh the record and if there will be a match you wil not add the contact.

Comment: i saved all my contacts in Arraylist.. But i am not able to compare that array list.. That Array list is in different class. When i call that array list it returns null value...